# Multiplying Cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

1) Let $ah$ be a coset of the subgroup $H$. Suppose there are two elements $ah_1\in aH$ and $ah_2\in aH$ such that $(ah_1)(ah_2)\in aH.$ Show that this implies that $a \in H$ and so $aH=H$.

2) Suppose $ah_1 \in aH$ and $bh_2 \in bH$. Suppose that $(ah_1)(bh_2)\in aH$. Show that this means $b \in H$ and $bH=H.$

3) Let $H$={$e, (13)$} be a subgroup of $S_3$. Find elements $a,b \in S_3$ where $bh_2ah_1 \in aH$, but $bH\ne H.$ This means left and right multiplication makes a difference.

Where do I go on these. I am just not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, notice that since $(ah_1)(ah_2) \in aH$, we know that there is some $h_3 \in H$ such that $ah_1ah_2 = ah_3$. Left-cancelling the $a$, it follows that $h_1ah_2  = h_3$. Rearranging to solve for $a$, it follows that $a = h_1^{-1}h_3h_2^{-1}$. But then since $H$ is a subgroup and is thus closed under multiplication and inverses, it follows that the RHS is in $H$ so that $a \in H$, as desired.

Try something similar for the other questions.